# Adding fractions in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple loop which adds fractions

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    sum += 1/(i+2);
}
return sum;
```

but it seems like Java doesn't understand fractions? Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try `1D/(i+2)`

Comment: `sum += (double)1/(i+2);` or `sum += 1.0d/(i+2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's doing integer division, cast it double

```
sum += (double)1 / (i + 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, using floating point variables (such as float or double in java) is always dangerous due to finite representation of them in binary system. For example:

```
double a = 1.000001;
double b = 2.0000001;
System.out.println(a+b);
```

will print 3.0000010999999995

In your code, expression

```
1/(i+2)
```

is treated as division of integers and 1/3 results in 0. Both expressions 1 and (i+2) are integers. To get more precise result you should know that any operation result will be returned in "the most needed precision". Which is - if one of your expression is of more precise type - such as long, float, double then resulting value will be of most precise type given. For example:

```
(2+3L) - expression result will be of long type
(2+2.1) - expression result will be of double type
(2.1f+2.0d) - expression result will be of double type
```

(L stands for long type)

There are several ways you can express floating point literals in Java:

1. value of **float** precision can be expressed with adding suffix 'f' or 'F' i.e. float a=1.2f
2. value of **double** precision can be expressed by adding suffix 'd' or 'D' i.e. double a=2.3D
3. apart from suffixes value type can be **casted** to required type using (float) or (double) operator i.e. float a = (float) 1.2;
4. another important thing is **default representation** of value without suffix. it's by default **double**, so exemplary:

   ```
   float a = 1.2;
   ```

   will not even compile, because such assigment will be concerned as lossy casting and compiler would require clear intent from programmer (this is usually done with adding suffix to values or casting value).

Answer (score 0):

since `i` in an integer, `1/(i+2)` will also produce an integer. 
you just need to use casting to double like this:

```
sum += 1.0d/(i+2);
```

when you write `1.0d` or `(double)1` you cast the number to double.
then the fraction will produce double and will be assign correctly to `sum`.